# How to iterate over many websites and parse text using web crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to parse text and run an sentiment analysis over the text from multiple websites. I have successfully been able to strip just one website at a time and generate a sentiment score using the TextBlob library, but I am trying to replicate this over many websites, any thoughts on where to start?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from textblob import TextBlob


url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/television/comments/38dqxf/josh_duggar_confessed_to_his_father_jim_bob/"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

#print(text)

wiki = TextBlob(text)
r = wiki.sentiment.polarity

print r
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you want to 'crawl' the web, you're going to have to parse each site for <a> tags and then save each one. Afterwards, you unpack their html one at a time and replicate the first step. Over and over and over.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail why specifically the <a> tag needs to be parsed and rather than creating a list a to parse in ?

Comment: Navigation from one site to another is generally done by clicking on links, so in essence, you want to parse out all of the links on a page. Then you can analyse it however you wish. Afterwards, you go through your list of links (<a href=""></a>) open them up one by one and repeat the above steps. By doing that, you're 'crawling' from one site to the next, by extracting links from each of the pages. The starting page of a crawler is usually called the 'seed' page.

Comment: would this method you have mentioned if I am not trying to parse the links out of just one "seed" url but all I am trying to do is simple, collect the text from the first page of every url, nothing fancy like getting all the links from one page. My urls would be (google.com, reddit.com, etc) not just one page. 

apologies for not being clear.

Comment: You want to get the link data from each of those pages or just the text?

Comment: just text is all I need I can then pass the text into the TextBlob library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get the data from a website via URL in python:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://reddit.com/')
html = response.read()
```

`html` is a string containing all of the HTML from the URL.

I'm not entirely sure what you want to get from each page. If you comment below, I could edit this answer and help you further.

Edit:

If you want to iterate through a list of URLs, you could create a function and go about it like this:

```
#you can add to this
urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.reddit.com"]


def parse_websites(list_of_urls):
    for url in list_of_urls:
        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        # kill all script and style elements

        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()    # rip it out

        # get text
        text = soup.get_text()

        # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        # break multi-headlines into a line each
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        # drop blank lines
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

        #print(text)

        wiki = TextBlob(text)
        r = wiki.sentiment.polarity

        print r

parse_websites(urls)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I want to run my script through many urls, seems those codes only function on one URL.

I am trying to simply extract the text from the first page of a list of websites. The script I have posted above strips the html from the website and only leaves text behind, which I am analyzing. 
Problem I am running into is that I do not understand how to make the script I have made iterate through a list of urls. This is the portion of code I am referring too. 

url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/television/comments/38dqxf/josh_duggar_confessed_to_his_father_jim_bob/"

Comment: Wow Thank you it worked! so my question now is can you please explain what you did in the above changes, based on a code perspective ?

Comment: Sure. So 'urls' is a list that contains strings of website addresses. In your code, you have the parsing logic, that you want to apply to each address. Therefore, we take that logic and encapsulate it into a function (parse_websites) that takes that list of addresses as a parameter. Afterwards, the list is then iterated through by using a 'for loop', whereby each address from the url list is parsed individually. Once that's all laid out, all you have to do is call the function to get it to run... aka parse_websites(urls)

Comment: I see thank you for you the answer, so does that mean if I want to work with the output (in this case print(r)), it would already be stored in a list and I could iterate over the function (parse_websites) like a list?

Comment: If you make the return value a list, then yes. The line would be, 'return r' not 'print r'. Then you can treat the function call as if its a list.